# Python 3.9, Pandas - how to append dataframe in existing excel

Tags: excel, pandas, append

In Python I have a Pandas data frame which I need to append to an existing one within excel (same file & sheet), like this:

[image]

This is easy enough if the file doesn't exist, though I'm having difficulty if it already exists and I want to append. I suspect the process is 'open same file in append mode'->'append df to the end'->'save and close', though I haven't quite got it. My simplified code:

```
  def process(saveName, labels, data):
    if not os.path.isfile(saveName):
        df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': labels, 'Value': data})
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter(saveName, engine='openpyxl')
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
        writer.save()
        writer.close()
    else:
        df = pd.DataFrame({'Value': data})

saveName = 'myFile.xlsx'
labels = ['A', 'B', 'C']
data = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]
process(saveName, labels, data)

saveName = 'myFile.xlsx'
data = [0.4, 0.5, 0.6]
process(saveName, labels, data)
```

Comment: `Excelwriter` has a mode parameter, which can be `a`, and `to_excel` has startrow and startcol parameters, to define the insert location. I haven't tried, but I guess that's how they envisioned it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not greatly Pythonic but if it helps someone then great.
Many thanks to @mcsoini for the suggestion, frustratingly I tried mode='a' using engine='openpyxl' and new data is appended though to a new sheet. The only way I could address this is:
i/ if the file exists already, open it (read dataframe, df)
ii/ remove all 'Unnamed columns' from df
iii/ insert new data at the end column of df
iv/ write over existing file

Very clunky but it works. Suggestions welcome - though please provide working example code.

```
def process(saveName, labels, data):
    if not os.path.isfile(saveName):
        df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': labels, 'Value': data})
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter(saveName)
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
        writer.save()
    else:
        df = pd.read_excel(saveName, sheet_name='Sheet1')
        for item in list(df):
            if 'Unnamed' in item:
                df = df.drop([item], axis=1)
        position = len(list(df))
        df.insert(position, 'Value', data, True)
        with pd.ExcelWriter(saveName) as writer:
            df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=0, startcol=0)

saveName = 'myFile.xlsx'
labels = ['A', 'B', 'C']
data = [0.4, 0.5, 0.6]
process(saveName, labels, data)
```